# Audio dubbed in Video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, video

Is there any way in html5, javascript or jquery to put audio dubbed a video. I wanted to have a video available in two languages and give the possibility to the user to choose the language he most desired. If I have the video in English and one in French audio is possible to overlap the audio?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's doable with HTML5. For example, you can use [MPEG-DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP) and a player that supports the required feature.